# SSIS 2008R2 - Use Package Config Value in Expression

Tags: ssis

Is it possible to add a SQL Server package configuration value for an **Expression** attribute on, for example, a 'Flat File Connection Manager'?

Comment: What's the use case for this? Normally you build your expression using configuration values

Comment: You cannot store or modify expressions through configurations or any other mechanism that I'm aware of

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. In you expression you can use: "+@[User::(variable name)]+"

More info: https://anothersqlgeek.wordpress.com/2013/03/28/ssis-dynamic-connections-part-1/

Comment: There is a root path that is the same format across all packages.

I am thinking of storing this root path as a Database Config value and assigning this value to a variable in the SSIS package. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: You can use a execute SQL task to set a variable using a query. In the Execute SQL Task Editor go to the 'Result Set' tab and you can add a new one, Result Name being a SQL variable that you set in your SQL statement, and the variable name being the package variable name.